# Audio recorder and translator program?

Tags: windows-7, speech-recognition

I am currently looking for a program for Windows 7 that records or listens to audio or human speech in another language, E.g. Japanese and then translates it into English.

I need a program that is ideally....

- Not costly or expensive
- Runs on Windows 7
- Is multi-lingual
- Is at least 90% accurate most of the time or well accurate
- Automatically types it all out in English
- Can detect the spoken language

Nice to haves are....

- At least simple or easy to use (Not expecting it though)
- Below $200 (Wouldn't be surprised if a program like this cost more), but would still be nice
- Can easily fine-tune it to my own needs easily
- Can at least recognize Japanese speech and then translate it

Any ideas?

Comment: Should it be able to run offline? Most such programs actually use a web service.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul- Offline or online. I don't really mind but as long as it is accurate and can fulfill at least most of my requirements. :)

Comment: Doesn't [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) now support this? I'm pretty sure it can translate what is heard in real time from one language to another.